# Physical system that is described by the conformal group's irreductible representations

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, education, representation-theory

I am currently studying the [conformal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_group) group, i.e the 15-dimensional group that is associated with the [conformal symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_symmetry) of spacetime.

Before working on that group, I've work on the [Poincaré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group) Lie group. I've seen, for example, how, by requiring that the universe respects the Poincaré invariance, we obtain the irreductible representations which describe the elementary system of a relativistic free particle. I've seen similar work done with the [Galilean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation) group, which leads this time to the irreductible representations which describe the elementary system of a non-relativistic free particle.

Now, I am assuming that one could follow the same procedure with the conformal group, and would obtain the irreductible representations which would describe another elementary system.

My question is: what would that physical system be?

Since the Poincaré group is a subgroup of the conformal group, I know that this system may be relativistic. Also, since the [De Sitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_space) group is also a subgroup of the conformal group, I know that spacetime doesn't necessary have to be flat (it could be curved). Thus, I wonder what properties such a system would have. Would it respect general relativity? (My intuition says no)

Any ideas/references would help!